# AngularJS $compile throws exception

Tags: angularjs

Why this throws an exception?

```
var item = {ID: 2, Name: "Andrej" };
var html = "<div>{{ID}} - {{Name}}</div>";
$compile(html)(item); // THIS THROWS EXCEPTION
```

Exception is (line 764)

```
TypeError: jqLite("<div>").append(element).html().match(/^(<[^>]+>)/) is null
```

Comment: @Andy Joslin, 1) can `$interpolate` take scope objects?. 2) If i use `$interpolate` on a template string with some object or scope object as context, will the template updates as i change that context?

+1 for the distinction bw `$compile` and `$interpolate`. Sorry i could not use "@Andy Joslin" in answer section. SO is automatically removing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to substitute values using the angular interpolator with an object, use `$interpolate`.

`$compile` is made for creating angularized elements, and requires a scope.

```
var item = {ID: 2, Name: "Andrej" };
var html = "<div>{{ID}} - {{Name}}</div>";
console.log($interpolate(html)(item)); // --> <div>2 - Andrej</div>
```