# AngularJS - AlertFactory open dialog behavior

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

i'm creating an AlertFactory because ui.bootstrap.dialog doesn't works in my app.

So i type follow code: http://jsfiddle.net/Premier/BHqKB/17/

```
enter code here
```

It works very well if you click on the "Open dialog" button: on screen appear a dialog with my messages.

I also register a listener on keydown: listener fires a broadcast event on which is registered a scope related function. This function calls openDialog to show the dialog. In this way angular doesn't interpolates arguments and alert is shown with {{title}} placeholder.

What is wrong in my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `$apply` to invoke a digest cycle.

```js
ng.element(document).on('keydown', function(e){
  //alert('keydown');
  //openDialog();
  $rootScope.$broadcast('openDialog');
  $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem is that 'MessageBoxController' was not instantiated and title, message and buttos are null after call $apply.

Comment: And when are those properties initialized?

Comment: I'm sorry, your solution works perfectly. Thank you. Problem was about my distraction about controller name: there was 2 controllers with name MessageBoxController