# Get HTML from $compile template

Tags: angularjs

```
function ($scope,$compile) {
    $scope.word="Habrahabra"


var template = $compile("<p>{ { name } }</p>")
var templ = template({name: "Ivan"})
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML =templ
}
```

in view i see

```
<p id="status">[[object HTMLParagraphElement]]</p>
```

How get string from object templ for append into  ?

Answer (score 3):

At first, you need to send real `$scope` into your `link` function returned by `$compile` function - otherwise it will not work as you wish. You can send your `$scope` in which you will declare your `name`, or you can make a copy of `$rootScope` or current `$scope`, in which you will declare your `name` variable.

Also, for append your element to DOM, you can use the second parameter of your `template()` function:

```
template($scope, function (element, scope) {
  angular.element(document.getElementById("status")).append(element);
})
```

Answering to your question - you can call `templ.html()` or `templ[0].innerHTML` to receive string, but you could do it after angular is bootstraped and `$digest()` was finished to work, so you must do with small huck like `setTimeout()` with time interval - 0:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = templ.html();
}, 0);
```

#### See simple example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WcwRvjwYGuc87Rx3LhHX?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

```
function Temp($scope,$compile) {
    var scope = $scope.$new(true);
    scope.name = "Ivan";
    var template = $compile("<p>{{ name }}</p>");
    var templ = template(scope);
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#status')).append(templ[0]);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/8754/)

Since you don't usually want to use the default scope for this compiled template, you could create an isolated scope by using: `$scope.$new(true)`.

> The key here is passing true to $new, which accepts one parameter for
>   isolate, which avoids inheriting scope from the parent.
>   - [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15560832/2806799)

**PS**: The space in between your braces, `var template = $compile("<p>{ { name } }</p>")`, causes problems with the compilation.