# html is not compile on append new child in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-compile

I am trying to insert a node dynamically, but the appended html is not getting compiled correctly.

[This is the code on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajithravindran/cho31y5e/2/).

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="appController"> 
    {{tittle}}
   <div name="name" ng-repeat="d in data" ng-click="click(d.id)" id="div{{d.id}}">{{d.id}} click me</div>
</div>
```

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $compile) {
        $scope.tittle = "test";
        $scope.data = [{ id: 1, child: [{name:'renjith'}] }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 6 }];
        $scope.click = function (data, $element) {
            debugger;
            var scope = { id: "12" };
          angular.element(document.querySelector("#div" + data)).append($compile("<div ngTransclude>{{d.id}}</div>")($scope.data));
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Using this works angular.element(document.querySelector("#div" + data)).append($compile("<div ngTransclude>{{data[0].child[0].name}}</div>")($scope)); It seems in ur code, u are passing a array and there is no variable to access the array. So I pass in just the scope and the array can be access via 'data' property

Comment: you should pass a real `$scope` to `$compile`. You can create a new isolated scope though. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559442/angularjs-how-can-i-create-a-new-isolated-scope-programmatically).

Comment: blessenm thank you but when i click next node it add the same data. i want  to update data from server

Comment: y i cant get the ng-repeated data d in appended node?

Comment: Amir thank you, can you edit my fiddle?

Comment: You will only get what you pass in the compiled template. Here the id is accessible https://jsfiddle.net/cho31y5e/4/

Comment: blessenm thank you, how can i create the same using  directive?