# how to create personal scope for each compiled element?

Tags: angularjs

When I create new 'wItem' object and want to  append compiled DOM to container(not ng-repeat)

```
 container.append($compile(UIService.appendItem())($scope));
 var children = container[0].children;
 var length = children.length-1;
 //take appended element and set new scope Item there
 var newEl = children[length];
 angular.element(newEl).scope().item = wItem;
```

UIService.appendItem

```
  function appendWorkItem() {
        return '<div  layout="column"  class=" workItem  workItemName" id={{item._id}}child > ' +
            '<div>{{item.name}}</div> ' +
            ' </div>'
    }
```

the result is:
First time

```
wItem[0] = {_id:1, name: item1}
```

, it creates wItem and appends to DOM!
second and other times I should be:

```
 wItem[1] = {_id:2, name: item2}
 wItem[2] = {_id:3, name: item3}
```

it creates new wItem and when it appends to DOM it updates previous created elements with the last wItem scope.and I getting this:

[image]

I am not so good in it,but I think it passes scope of last element to prev ones. How to fix it?

Comment: Your $compile code, is this implemented in a directive?  If so include the entire code.

Comment: no it is in controller

Comment: It is considered bad practice to modify the DOM in a controller.  Your elements are at the same scope level, so naturally you are simply overwriting the scope property 'item'.

Comment: how to make in better way? if create directive, where to put it?

Comment: `$scope.items = [ { ... }, { ... } ]` and `<div ng-repeat="item in items"></div>`

Comment: This is a basic situation in which you should definitely be using ng-repeat... DOM manipulation outside directives = bad

Comment: how to use it inside directive? I mean where to set directive with it's scope?

Comment: If you wanted to put the whole thing in a directive, it would still not make any sense not to use ng-repeat.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ghG0KnLsCrhSRqDoBnUG?p=preview

Comment: used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559442/angularjs-how-can-i-create-a-new-isolated-scope-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't manipulate the DOM from your controller.  Controllers provide scope and are generally nothing but scoping glue for views and models.

Get familiar with [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) because they're practically required.  Similarly it is critical to understand [scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).  Failing to understand scopes and directives will doom your angular efforts.

Here's a directive implementing your UIService.  It can be done other ways.

```
  .directive("workItem", ['UIService', function(uiservice) {
    return {
      scope: {
        item: "="
      },
      template: function() {
        return uiservice.appendWorkItem();
      }
    }
  }])
```

As has been pointed out you need to familiarize yourself with the **ng-repeat** directive.  An example using the workItem directive and ng-repeat might look like this

```
<div ng-controller="WorkItems">  
   <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <work-item item="item"></work-item>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wr0Do2Oo82rzLgSulwEq?p=preview) demonstrating the above directive used with ng-repeat.

I suggest staying away from [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) until you have a good grasp of directives and scopes (and actually have a bona fide reason to use it).